# Unable to execute Selenium WebDriver command on Javascript function enabled button

Tags: javascript, java, selenium

I am referring to http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onclick_copy. On clicking the button, it is supposed to copy the value in field1 to field2. I tried to automate it with selenium webdriver. 
I am using `WebDriver` commands as:

```
driver.get("http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onclick_copy");
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//button[@onclick='myFunction()']")).click();
```

But I got the error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":".//button[@onclick='myFunction()']"}
Command duration or timeout: 20.11 seconds
```

After that I tried:

```
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
jse.executeScript("document.getElementById(\"field2\").value = document.getElementById(\"field1\").value;");
```

This time I got the error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: document.getElementById(...) is null
```

Comment: Thank you JeffC for formatting the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your button is inside an iframe. You have to switch to the frame before find the element.
See code below:

```
driver.get("http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onclick_copy");  
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.id("iframeResult"))); 
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//button[@onclick='myFunction()']")).click();
```

Comment: Now it also works with JavaScript: driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.id("iframeResult")));JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;jse.executeScript("return document.getElementById(\"field2\").value = document.getElementById(\"field1\").value;");

Comment: @MLShivaPrasad thanks, I've updated the answer accordingly.